# Permission denied when deleting file in Dockerfile as new user after creating the file and changing ownership

Tags: linux, docker

**This is my docker file**

FROM ubuntu 
WORKDIR /   
RUN touch file1 
RUN adduser luffy 
RUN chown luffy file1 
USER luffy 
RUN rm file1

When I try to build an image from this docker file it gives me an error
[image]
Any suggestion ??

I am expecting that I should be able to build a docker image from my docker file

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the error message in plain text and not an image file?  The Dockerfile and title suggest you're just asking a question about the permissions required to run `rm` and not really about programming _per se_, and another site like [unix.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Change `RUN chown luffy file1` into `RUN chmod a+rw file1`.